# Pandas Create new column based on a count and a condition from another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

### Problem

I have a dataframe `df` with products like this :

```
ID  DATE        TYPE    Client_ID
1   2015-01-15  A       johndoe
2   2009-01-15  C       johndoe
3   2015-03-12  C       johndoe
4   2010-01-01  B       johndoe
5   2017-01-01  B       johndoe
6   2018-01-01  A       markdoe
7   2019-01-01  C       johndoe
8   2012-01-01  C       markdoe
```

From this one I create a dataframe with only A-types products, `df-A` :

```
ID  DATE        TYPE    Client_ID
1   2015-01-15  A       johndoe
6   2018-01-01  A       markdoe
```

What I want is to create to `df-A` 2 variables that count the number of type-B and type-C products owned by the client with date lower or equal to the A product analysed one.
The result I want :

```
ID  DATE        TYPE    Client_ID   NB-B    NB-C
1   2015-01-15  A       johndoe     1       1
6   2018-01-01  A       markdoe     0       1
```

`NB-B` of 1st row is 1 since `johndoe` has 2 B-products, but only one has `Date <= 2015-01-15` (this product is `ID=4`, with date `2010-01-01`)

### What I tried :

I did it using `iterrows` or `apply`. This might work but it take ages, I really need to make it faster with some groupby and aggregations.

```
for index, row in df-A.iterrows():
    row['NB-B'] = df[(df['ID'] == row['ID']) & (df['DATE'] <= row['DATE'])].groupby('TYPE').count()['ID'].loc['B']
```

The same with `apply`

```
def B(x):
    return(row['NB-B'] = df[(df['ID'] == x['ID']) & (df['DATE'] <= x['DATE'])].groupby('TYPE').count()['ID'].loc['B'])

df-A.apply(lambda x: B(x), axis=1)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

### EDIT : Details after @Quang Hoang answer

One Client can have multiple type-A products at a different date (I didn't mention it to simplify as the problem was already complex, I didn't expect to make a big change). Also, I want to count, like Bs and Cs, the number of A products owned by the client after the new one is bought.

Example :

```
ID  DATE        TYPE    Client_ID
1   2015-01-15  A       johndoe
2   2009-01-15  C       johndoe
3   2015-03-12  C       johndoe
4   2010-01-01  B       johndoe
5   2017-01-01  B       johndoe
6   2020-01-01  A       johndoe
7   2019-01-01  C       johndoe
```

Expected result :

```
ID  DATE        TYPE    Client_ID   NB-A   NB-B    NB-C
1   2015-01-15  A       johndoe     1      1       1
6   2018-01-01  A       johndoe     2      2       3
```

This detail is important, since applying your code, I got the following error : `Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` since `Client_ID`, which becomes the new index of `s`, is not unique.

I tried to fix the issue but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try pivot_table and join:

```
# extract the A types
aType = df.TYPE.eq('A')
s = df[aType].set_index('Client_ID')

(df[~aType].assign(valid=lambda x: x['DATE'].le(x['Client_ID'].map(s['DATE'])).astype(int))
   .pivot_table(index='Client_ID',columns='TYPE',
                values='valid', aggfunc='max',
                fill_value=0)
   .add_prefix('NB_')
   .join(s)
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
  Client_ID  NB_B  NB_C  ID        DATE TYPE
0   johndoe     1     1   1  2015-01-15    A
1   markdoe     0     1   6  2018-01-01    A
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! However, I'm still facing a problem. I edited my original post to show more details and explain the issue I couldn't resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
Pandas.Series.str.count("string")
```

you extract the columns you want to count as a serie then appli the `serie.str.count("the string you are looking for")`

```
series = df["Client_ID"] 
  
count = series.str.count("johndoe")
```

You can use loop to get all the names in the "Client_ID" series

This will count all the occurence of "johndoe" in the columns "Client_ID"

Comment: This is similar to the solutions I already tried. This might work but it's really long since you have to loop on every `df-A` rows, and each time separate a sub-dataframe from `df` then make the count